# Uploading file in JSP without changing enctype

Tags: jsp, upload

I want to upload a file from a jsp but my limitation is that i cannot change the enctype of the form due to a custom framework we are using. I know of course that control input of type "file" needs enctype="multipart/form-data" but i was wondering if it is possible to achieve the same functionality without changing enctype of the form. I am familiar with commons-fileupload etc but i cannot think a flow that the user is browsing a page with textboxes etc and at the same time he can add a file and submit the form at one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. The different form encoding type is not invented just for fun only or so.

Fix your custom framework. Or switch to a *real* framework instead of homebrewing one.

Note that this problem is not specific to JSP. It's just the way how HTTP/HTML works.

Comment: I was actually thinking if there is way when the user selects a file to upload it asynchronously to a path at the serverand when the user submits the form to have that path in a hidden field or something.

Comment: If that doesn't go through your custom framework, then you could of course also go in this direction and then use another framework to properly parse the file upload.

Comment: @MultipartConfig annotation on servlet solved the problem. I can use enctype="multipart/form-data" in my forms and at the same time framework's behaviour is the same.

Comment: That's indeed one of the right fixes. Haven't you tried it in first place at all? Your question implied that this was not possible.

Comment: No i didnt tried. I came acroos with this annotation while doing my search for a solution. I guess i was not clear enough in my question. Initial problem was that when changing enctype request.getParam etc didnt work, which makes sense. Thanks anyway.